# no response from microsd card

Tags: microcontroller

I was trying to interface a 64 mb MicroSD card with MicroChip MCU. I sent `cmd0-addr3-addr2-addr1-addr0-crc` but didn't got any response.

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

From the way you've phrased the question, it sounds like you don't have a very good understanding of *how* to communicate with external peripherals in general, on an embedded device.  You should  reference [Microchip AN1169](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01169a.pdf) which goes into detail on implementing SD card communication with an SD card.  If that's not enough help, Microchip's application engineers are usually very helpful - don't rule out calling one.

On the other hand, if the application note is still over your head, you should strongly consider starting off with a less ambitious project - something like driving a motor or other simple IO that is not address-bound.  The addressing issues can become very difficult when you already aren't familiar with embedded programming.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this thread because I was facing a similar problem. I know this thread is old but I want to post my experience here just for the record.

I have been doing FS and device programming for more than 8 yrs now so I am not a newbie :)

I was trying out PIC32MX and its inbuilt libraries for the first time and ran into the same problem as mentioned in the question. I double checked my connections after which I started doubting the library. I downloaded the latest versions for fixes but same behavior.

After lot of debugging for both hardware and software I found out that the microsd sockets contact for power was not sticking to the card contact at all! No power No response!